# Encryption technique in Java to preserve the format of the input text

Tags: java, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I want to encrypt data in specific columns in my database table. But, with standard Encryption with a secret key using AES/GCM, the cipher text after encrypting is much longer in length than the original text.

Since, each database column has a specific length, I do not want the encrypted text to be longer than the original text. I have looked all through the web for a FormatPreservingEncryption sample in Java but have not found. Seems, this technique is not used much.

I have already tried the code from https://github.com/idealista/format-preserving-encryption-java

It is not running correctly for large text. For example, it fails for text which are more than 228 characters in length.

Can anybody please help in either providing a source code implementation of such a technique in java or pointing out some alternate technique to achieve what i want. I use the standard Cipher class in Java to do the encoding right now.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There are 2 difficulties to overcome: 1) The need for a random nonce/IV and 2) the need for an integrity check. With some creativity and expertise it is possible that both can be overcome. For example, perhaps you can store the integrity check in another column (yechh!) or somewhere else, or dispense with it altogether if you're prepared to live with the resulting loss of security. As for the IV perhaps you can create one from the row and column information. Perhaps from something else. If you can solve these two then an "AES/CTR/NoPadding" cipher can be used.

Comment: It also sound like it's not the format you want to preserve but rather the length.

Answer (score 1):

In the link below there is an example of how to encrypt text of the same length as the input text using CipherStream.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/BasicIOexamplewithCTRusingAES.htm

May be it will help somebody